# Fluid height of middle element

Tags: html, css, liquid-layout

Take a look at this [piece of code](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7gKB/)

The height of the div is set to 100px, and `overflow: hidden` is hiding the content over 100px. What I want to do is to make the `<ul>` element fluid so regardless of the height of the parent div, the `<h2>` element stays at the top, `.controlpanel` div stays at the bottom and the `<ul>` element resizes to fit. I tried using percentage heights but it's possible to get them accurate.

Comment: The `ul` alone is `~140px` high. If the parent's `height` is only `100px`, how is everything supposed to fit?

Comment: The `ul`'s height needs to be liquid.

Comment: So hiding some of the text in the `ul` is acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is, scrollbars are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to understand the question :P but i think i got the gist of what you want, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/Y7gKB/9/

Comment: That's it! Sorry I should've taken some time to clear the question out to everybody.

Comment: It's ok :D, happens to me all the time as well. Structure is hard to convey :/

Comment: The fiddle link result is not fluid height in the middle hehe

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7gKB/5/

Not sure if thats what you wanted?

Comment: No, what I want is... for instance, I set the div's height to 500px, it should stretch to 500px.

Comment: bit confused what you mean by "Stretch to" but have updated fiddle

Comment: @Lollero - Close but I cannot use absolute position because I'm using a liquid layout.

Comment: @benhowdle89 Not quite. I added `position: relative;` into  `div#settings` to your code.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa could you elaborate on that? It is liquid, it moves the update to the bottom of the outer div no matter what its height is. Since the height is now set to 500px then that is where it stays.

Comment: by "update" i meant the controlpanel and the button, dunno why i called it update.

Comment: @Lollero - It moves the bottom div correctly. But the height of the `ul` does not change. If I reduce the height of the div to 100px, the height of the `ul` remains the same and the bottom div overlaps the `ul`'s content.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa I'm not sure what you mean by the `ul` height changing.. Well same thing with the overlapping, I mean what do you expect the ul to do when you set height to the outer div to something that is smaller than the ul height? But about the controlpanel overlapping When you havent set any height, you can deal with what by adding padding to the bottom of the ul http://jsfiddle.net/Y7gKB/7/